shell fragment: compare against fixed string
I'm abusing Make to run some tests for me, and I need to compare the output of a command against a fixed string, ideally with a somewhat readable construct.
The best thing I can do if $SHELL is bash is:
./cmd --with --lots $(EXTRA_PARAMETERS) | cmp <(echo expected)

which is quite close to what I want, but the dependency on bash makes this a lot less portable than it could be.
The obvious alternative is
[ "$(./cmd --with --lots $(EXTRA_PARAMETERS))" = "expected" ]

which is a bit difficult to split up across multiple lines, and also more sensitive to the contents of $(EXTRA_PARAMETERS), because the command is inside a substitution.
Is there a (POSIX) way to compare stdin against a fixed string and return a non-zero exit code on mismatch, or a shell construct that I'm not seeing that solves this in an elegant way.
(Ideally, this would work as a self-contained fragment because I'm using it from a Makefile and would like to avoid rewriting the entire test framework -- even though it is tempting)

what do you mean with "also more sensitive to the contents of $(EXTRA_PARAMETERS)"?

@ilkkachu, while the $(...) sets up a lot of protection, I'm not entirely sure I can use quotation marks the way I'd expect it.

um, so you don't really know it'd be "more sensitive", right? Have you experienced any issues with it?

For readability, you could use
result=$(
    ./cmd \
        --with \
        --lots \
        $(EXTRA_PARAMETERS)
)

if [ "$result" = "$expected" ]; then
   echo ok
else
   echo nok
fi

That is, put the output of your command in a separate variable, and let the command substitution span multiple script lines by using line continuations.
This makes it more readable, and also separates the running of the command from the testing of its result.
Would you want to use cmp, you could do so if you write the output of your command to a file:
./cmd --with --lots $(EXTRA_PARAMETERS) >test.out

if printf '%s\n' "$expected" | cmp -s test.out; then
   echo ok
else
   echo nok
fi

# later
rm -f test.out

This is a good option if you have the expected test results on file already (which is sometimes the case).  Here, the expected result is stored in testcase-001:
# Test: testcase-001

./cmd --with --lots $(EXTRA_PARAMETERS) >test.out

if cmp -s test.out testcase-001; then
   echo ok
else
   echo nok
fi

# later
rm -f test.out

Or, skipping the output file,
# Test: testcase-001

./cmd --with --lots $(EXTRA_PARAMETERS) |
if cmp -s testcase-001; then
   echo ok
else
   echo nok
fi

